# HTML mail - how to properly format message

Tags: hooks

I am trying to implement html mail notifications using htmlmail module. I am not certain if message should be formatted as array in `$message["body][]` before the template or passed as a string in `$message['body']`.

The reason I am asking is that I first expected the email to be sent in as a string but then saw the `HTMLMAILSystem::format` function that flattens the body array:

```
  public function format(array $message) {
    $eol = variable_get('mail_line_endings', MAIL_LINE_ENDINGS);
    // @todo Remove this when issue #209672 gets resolved.
    $default_from = variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'));
    if ( !empty($message['headers']['From'])
      && $message['headers']['From'] == $default_from
      && valid_email_address($default_from)
    ) {
      $message['headers']['From'] = '"'
      . str_replace('"', '', variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal'))
      . '" <' . $default_from . '>';
    }
    // Collapse the message body array.
    if (module_exists('mailmime')) {
      $body = $this->formatMailMIME($message);
      $plain = $message['MailMIME']->getTXTBody();
    }
    else {
      if (is_array($message['body'])) {
        $message['body'] = implode("<br />$eol<br />$eol", $message['body']);
      }
      $body = theme('htmlmail', $message);
      if ($message['body'] && !$body) {
        watchdog(
          'htmlmail',
          'The %theme function did not return any text.  Please check your template file for errors.',
          array('%theme' => "theme('htmlmail', \$message)"),
          WATCHDOG_WARNING
        );
        $body = $message['body'];
      }
```

So if I understood correctly, message must be preformatted with correct html in `$message["body"][]` , but I am not 100% sure there are lots of code-bits involved for email sendouts. I also need to validate if this will allow me to send mail as plaintext?

Comment: Where are the email notifications originating from? Custom module? Are you worried whether or not they are going to be formatted in HTML or not?

Comment: Wow, this was asked two and a half years ago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7, it's the implementation of [`MailSystemInterface::format()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/MailSystemInterface%3A%3Aformat/7) that formats the message body and changes it to a string; before that, `$message['body']` is supposed to be an array.
In Drupal 6, [`drupal_mail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/6) receives an array for `$message['body']`, and changes it in a string.

```
// drupal_mail() in Drupal 6

// Build the e-mail (get subject and body, allow additional headers) by
  // invoking hook_mail() on this module. We cannot use module_invoke() as
  // we need to have $message by reference in hook_mail().
  if (function_exists($function = $module . '_mail')) {
    $function($key, $message, $params);
  }

  // Invoke hook_mail_alter() to allow all modules to alter the resulting e-mail.
  drupal_alter('mail', $message);

  // Concatenate and wrap the e-mail body.
  $message['body'] = is_array($message['body']) ? drupal_wrap_mail(implode("\n\n", $message['body'])) : drupal_wrap_mail($message['body']);
```

Compare the code you are showing with the code used by the Drupal 7 implementation ([`DefaultMailSystem::format()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.mail.inc/function/DefaultMailSystem%3A%3Aformat/7)).

```
public function format(array $message) {
  // Join the body array into one string.
  $message['body'] = implode("\n\n", $message['body']);
  // Convert any HTML to plain-text.
  $message['body'] = drupal_html_to_text($message['body']);
  // Wrap the mail body for sending.
  $message['body'] = drupal_wrap_mail($message['body']);
  return $message;
}
```

Drupal requiring `$message['body']` to be an array of strings is made clear in [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7), which describes it as follows:

- 'body': An array of strings containing the message text. The message body is created by concatenating the individual array strings into a single text string using "\n\n" as a separator.

Since `hook_mail_alter()` is invoked right before the `format()` method, that method is supposed to get an array, not a string.

```
 // drupal_mail() in Drupal 7

 // Bundle up the variables into a structured array for altering.
  $message = array(
    'id' => $module . '_' . $key,
    'module' => $module,
    'key' => $key,
    'to' => $to,
    'from' => isset($from) ? $from : $default_from,
    'language' => $language,
    'params' => $params,
    'send' => TRUE,
    'subject' => '',
    'body' => array(),
  );

  //  …

  // Build the e-mail (get subject and body, allow additional headers) by
  // invoking hook_mail() on this module. We cannot use module_invoke() as
  // we need to have $message by reference in hook_mail().
  if (function_exists($function = $module . '_mail')) {
    $function($key, $message, $params);
  }

  // Invoke hook_mail_alter() to allow all modules to alter the resulting e-mail.
  drupal_alter('mail', $message);

  // Retrieve the responsible implementation for this message.
  $system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);

  // Format the message body.
  $message = $system->format($message);
```

The only reason I could see to check if `$message['body']` is a string is to protect the code against modules not correctly updated in the passage from Drupal 5 to Drupal 6. In fact, Drupal 5 passed a string for body, as evident in the example for [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_mail_alter/5) shown in the documentation.

```
function hook_mail_alter(&$mailkey, &$to, &$subject, &$body, &$from, &$headers) {
  $body .= "\n\n--\nMail sent out from " . variable_get('sitename', t('Drupal'));
}
```